# Unable to fire SelectedIndexChanged Event for a single item in a combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, combobox

I had gone through through some of the common questions here in the forum only:
[Select Index does not fire for a single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541789/selectedindexchanged-event-does-not-fire-if-item-is-already-selected-in-dropdown)

But I have two combobox related to each other, the value selected in the A determines the value in the B and on selcting the B combobox item, data is displayed.
So I want the event, even for a single item in the B combobox.

Should I append a select item in the B Combobox so that user selects( but that is the last option).

Comment: The solution to this question is that we need to write a method if there is a single item in the dropdown list and also it should work for other cases as well like when there are more than one item than it should show by default for the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other solution as well, one is to call the event of the same selected index event in the page load method.
So in this manner we can show the result of single item as well. This is not the best way but it worked out for me.